# Change form (create to update) using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple review system where users can select a number of stars and this creates an AJAX call to the `create` action (if the review is new).

If the review already exists, I want it to instead call the `update` action.

Right now, if the page loads to a blank review, the first change will call `create`, but so will all subsequent requests until I completely reload the page.

How can I get `create.js.erb` to change the reviews form from `create` to `update` without refreshing the page?

#### Clarification

If a particular user enters the page for the first time, they should be able to create a review, then edit their own review, without needing to refresh the page. My problem is that the create **then** update transition isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want that. Is it really implemented the way that there is only one review and it gets updated over and over again by more and more users? Because an obvious implementation would be to create a completely new review every time and never use update action.

I mean:

```
class ItemReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @item.reviews.create(params[:review])   # TODO check for errors and redirect
  end
end
```

with routes:

```
resources :items do
  resources :reviews
end
```

If I am wrong, please write more about your motivation for that solution.

Comment: árik - I do have each user submitting their own review, but imagine the case for a new user to the site. They come in and select a rating (this creates their review). When they then decide to change that rating, the form needs to update this review instead of trying to create a new one again. For clarity, I only meant that THIS user should first be able to create then update without refreshing the page.

Comment: Well, if I understand well, the user cannot post more than one rating, since when he posts his first one, the user interface changes to 'update'. Why don't you just leave it as a 'create' action and decide at the server whether it is first comment (then proceed insert to the db) or he's changing his opinion (then proceed update to the db). The controller interface does not have to necessarily copy the model interface.

Comment: árik - I was having trouble redirecting properly from `create` to `update` - it would always be picked up by the `show` action, which would then claim it couldn't find a record with `id='update'`!